# Open external webpage server side ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm dealing with an ASP.NET MVC4 project with Razor view engine.
I have the need to open an external webpage server side and render it to the client after it has loaded. The point is that the webpage and the server must be on the same domain (for security reasons) and this is not valid for the client.
Is it possible to open the link in the server and then present it to the client so that it appears like the original page (including all the scripting content)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send an HTTP request to the remote location ([`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and then return the results to the client. Basically this will give you the contents of the remote webpage as a string. Depending on how exactly you want to *present* it to the user there might be different approaches. For example you could inject it to some `<div>` of your current view after stripping of course the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags that might be present and getting just the inner contents of the body. You could use the HTML Agility Pack library to parse the contents of the remote page and extract only the necessary parts.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, you could use AJAX and CORS

**For Example:**

```
 alert(formData); 
                $.support.cors = true; 
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "http://localhost:89/API/Values", 
                    type: "POST", 
                    crossDomain: true, 
                    data: formData, 
                    dataType: "html", 
                    success: function (result) { 
                        alert('Server Side call Completed: Successful'); 
                        $('#Result').html(result);                          
                    }, 
                    error: function (jqXHR, tranStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        alert('Error');                             
                    } 
                });
```